# bash variable reevaluation

Tags: sh

This is a total newbie question but i'm struggling so I apologize.

I'm using bourne shell for an init script.

I have a variable
A=1
B="Welcome to world #$A"

Somewhere down the script i have a loop that updates A to 2,3,4 etc...  How do I get B to get re-evaluated?  At present, B stays "Welcome to world #1" the whole time.

Thanks!

UPDATE #1 - some code:

```
#!/bin/sh

A=1
B="Welcome to #$A"

repeatloop() {
  for i in {1..5}
  do
    A=$i
    echo $B
  done
}

repeatloop
```

Output:

```
Welcome to #1
Welcome to #1
Welcome to #1
Welcome to #1
Welcome to #1
```

I'm trying to get #2,#3,#4....

Answer (score 2):

You will need to do the assignment to `B` each time you do the assignment to `A`:

```
#!/bin/sh

A=1
B="Welcome to #$A"

repeatloop() {
  for i in {1..5}
  do
    A=$i
    B="Welcome to #$A"
    echo $B
  done
}

repeatloop
```

By the way `#!/bin/sh` is not Bash (even if it's a symlink to it).

Answer (score 2):

You can set your B argument as an [eval](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eval.1p.html) statement. Then just call it inside the loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

A=1
B='eval echo "Welcome to #$A"'

repeatloop() {
  for i in {1..5}
  do
    A=$i
    $B
  done
}

repeatloop
```

Output:

```
Welcome to #1
Welcome to #2
Welcome to #3
Welcome to #4
Welcome to #5
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type...

```
B="Welcome to the world #$A"
```

the value of $A is expanded *before* assigning a value to B. Which means that what you've typed there is equivalent to...

```
B="Welcome to the world #1"
```

So "re-evaluating" makes no sense, because B doesn't actually have a variable in it.

If you want variables to not be expanded until something is actually referenced, use a function instead:

```
function B() {
    echo "Welcome to the world $1"
}

A=1
welcomeone=$(B $A)

A=2
welcometwo=$(B $A)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, B is set with the value of what A currently is.  If you want it to update, you'll have get it from a function that recreates the value of B with the new value of A.

Think about it in another language like c/java.

```
int a = 0;
string b = "blah blah blah" + a; // b= "blah blah blah0"
a = 4;
//b still equals "blah blah blah0"
```

Comment: B is not a function, it is not 'executed'.

Comment: your example didnt have that, all it had was some text assigned to B like a variable

Comment: ...and assigning text to B does not make B a function.